# "ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects"

Tags: aiohttp, ta-lib, python-binance

I got this error when i updated python to 3.12 I'm trying to install python-binance library

Answers online were kinda fouge I didn't get what they said i'm semi-new to programming so I need some clear answers with details of the process please I also got the same error when i tried to install TA-lib library

Comment: Does this answer your question? [warning C4996: 'Py\_OptimizeFlag': deprecated in 3.12 aiohttp/\_websocket.c(3042): error C2039: 'ob\_digit': is not a member of '\_longobject'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77388920/warning-c4996-py-optimizeflag-deprecated-in-3-12-aiohttp-websocket-c3042)

Answer (score 4):

Python 3.12 is [not supported yet](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/7739#issuecomment-1773868351) in regular releases. For Python 3.12 install the beta [3.9.0b0](https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/3.9.0b0/):

`pip install aiohttp>=3.9.0b0`

Comment: this worked for me...